# Unity Объект виден в редакторе, но не виден в игре

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android

Через instansiate создаю объект (Наклонная штука на скриншоте). Она почему то видна в редакторе, но не отображается в игре. Как это можно исправить? Почему такое происходит?

```
instSlop = Instantiate(BuildObjects[0], Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятнее всего дело в материалах, настройках обьекта или скрипте который на обьекте может висеть. Вряд ли дело в строке добавляющей обьект. Предлагаю пересоздать обьект с нуля, убрать все скрипты и добавлять на сцену его этой же строкой. Плавно приводя к тому виду в котором он сейчас.

Comment: Оказалось клон просто создавался за фоном) Спасибо.

Comment: @user11184201 Помогите с этим, пожалуйста